# Factorial: product over primes

Tags: prime-numbers, factorial, gamma-function

Does

> $$\prod_{n=1}^{x}p_{n}$$

($p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime)
have a name or has it been been used in math? Does it matter? And Is there an analytical continuation of it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the answer of Donald Splutterwit, as a complement for the remaining question, the closest expression similar to an [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) I can recall is the [first Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function):

> $$\vartheta(x)=\sum_{p \le x} \log {p}$$

In essence, it is equal to the natural logarithm of the primorial of $x$, which is the product of all the existing primes up to $x$, and $x$ indeed can be any real number as long as the prime numbers are positive integers:

> $$\vartheta(x)=\sum_{p \le x} \log {p}= \log{p_1} + \log{p_2} + \cdots + \log{p_n} = log {\ (p_1p_2\cdots\ p_n)} = \log {\prod_{n=1}^{x}p_n}$$

Thus:

> $$\prod_{n=1}^{x}p_n=e^{\vartheta(x)}, x \in \Bbb R$$

Said that, I am not sure if this is really practical as a true [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) or not, but it provides a continuation over $\Bbb R$. For instance Ramanujan used the Chebyshev functions to prove [Bertrand's postulate](http://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/CamUnivCpapers/Cpaper24/page1.htm), and for that proof he linked the Chebyshev functions applied to the problem, with [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) and the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) (extension of the factorial function), so in practice they seem close to an analytic extension.

Answer (score 1):

It is called the primorial. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeProducts.html.
It is used in the proof that there are an infinite number of primes ... Assume there is a finte number of primes $p_1,p_2, \cdots , p_N$, then consider 
\begin{eqnarray*}
P= \prod_{i=1}^{N} p_i +1
\end{eqnarray*}
This cannot be divisible by any of the previous primes ... contradicting the assumption that there are a finite number of primes.

Comment: This is not the prime number theorem, it's the much older (by a millennium or two) result that there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: @ErickWong ... You are absolutely correct. I have edited my answer. Thank you for bringing this to my attention. $\ddot \smile$